# Undrestanding docker: what is the dockerhub Ubuntu image?

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu

I configured Windows Subsystem for Linux, installed a Microsoft packaged Ubuntu on Win 10, to get my hands on Docker using Linux. From what I understood, Docker does not need a guest OS, unlike VMWare - that's one of the main advantages.

I browsed the dockerhub and found an official [Ubuntu image](https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu). What is it for, as there is no need of a guest OS?

Comment: That's for you to build your own images on top of, e.g. using `FROM ubuntu:<version>` in your `Dockerfile`.

Comment: As opposed to the image running on a guest OS, the container image will run as in effect a single process. This will mean much smaller "foot print"

Answer (score 0):

Shared OS is probably the wrong term here, because many include the Linux distribution and filesystem as part of the OS. Containers run with a shared Linux kernel, but in isolated namespaces from the host and each other. One of those namespaces is the mount namespace, including your root filesystem. Therefore when you enter a container, the files in `/bin` and other directories are assembled from the image (plus volume mounts, and changes made within the container).

The Ubuntu docker image is an initial filesystem that includes a minimal Ubuntu environment you can use the create other images for running your containers. If you were to start a container without that, you wouldn't have anything, no `/bin/sh`, no `apt`, no libraries, and would have to create every binary and needed libraries to run commands inside the container first.

Comment: I see. Imagine you need a web server like nginx, you want to provide it in a container. Do you need to install it into an image derived from, let's say Ubuntu, or can you extend a scratch Docker image?

Comment: @sugarman when you pull an image, you get everything you need to run it. Gets a bit into the details, but the image includes a collection of tars/layers, each referenced by a sha256 digest on that content, and when you derive a new image, you start from that list of references. Docker and registry servers handles all the deduplication so you only keep one instance of that tar/layer, while pulling it if you don't already have it.

Comment: @sugarman and if you look at the nginx image, you'll see that the official image themselves based it on top of debian: https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/0f300ed4ae80724c569c9694bf89014e96ab567b/mainline/debian/Dockerfile

Comment: I'm new to Docker. I thought you could install various servers each in a separate image/container and allow them "to plug" into your hosts ressources, giving them the environement they need. Now, I understand that the container and host are isolated. So, you need for each server-container an OS environment basis. Let's say Ubuntu, will pe replicated for each server-container - the "base" is replicated.